# create dict with multiple values out of two lists. group multiple keys into one

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two list:

```
lists = ['a','b','c','d','e']
keys = [18,18,3,4,5]
```

what I want is a dictionary like this:

```
{18:['a','b'],3:'c',4:'d',5:'e'}
```

I keep getting this:

```
{18: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 3: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 4: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 5: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']}
```

I appreciate any advice!!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
dicts = {key: [] for key in keys}
for k, v in zip(keys, lists):
    dicts[k].append(v)
```

or

```
from collections import defaultdict
dicts = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in zip(keys, lists):
    dicts[k].append(v)
```

Output:

```
{18: ['a', 'b'], 3: ['c'], 4: ['d'], 5: ['e']}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer! Be aware that, realistically, it's unlikely to be accepted after the question poster has already posted their own answer that they're happy with.

Answer (score 0):

Upon reading a post suggestion from stackoverflow:

```
dictionary = {k: [values[i] for i in [j for j, x in enumerate(keys) if x == k]] for k in set(keys)}
```

I have solved it.

Comment: Seems like that generates lists even where there's only one element for a key, but you asked for those to appear directly as values.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
output = {}
for index, key in enumerate(keys):
    if not key in output:
        output[key] = lists[index]
    else:
        cur_val = output[key]
        if type(cur_val) == str:
            cur_val = [cur_val]
        
        cur_val.append(lists[index])        
        output[key] = cur_val
print(output)
```

output:

```
{18: ['a', 'b'], 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e'}
```

Answer (score -1):

Easy way is to use zip.

```
dictionary = dict(zip(keys, values))
```

Comment: This will produce `{18: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e'}` this output instead of `{18:['a','b'],3:'c',4:'d',5:'e'}`

Comment: Then how about:   for key, value in zip(list_one, list_two): d[key].append(value)

Comment: That wouldn't work either because the first time the value is added the `.append()` method would fail because there's no value for that key in the list. You could use `defaultdict(list)` to solve that, but then you would get lists even when there's only one element, but the OP just wanted the element directly in that case. You could solve that by doing another pass throught the dictionary and replacing one-element lists with their entries.